# Cannot use vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR to create vulkan surface

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, sdl-2, vulkan

I want to use vulkan with SDL2 but I am stuck at the surface creation stage, i cannot use **vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR** extension function as well as **VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR** extension struct as they are undefined, while i don't have any issues using other extension elements like **(vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR , etc ..)**, does the surface extension needs a separate header file? how can i get it to work?

the preprocessor directives i use are as follows

```
#include <vulkan\vulkan.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
```

Please note that i have used Vulkan with glfw without having any program this is my second attempt of running vulkan, so i don't think i have any driver support issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the `#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` *before* you `#include <vulkan\vulkan.h>`

then you can grab the native info you need from SDL_GetWindowWMInfo.

Comment: thank you for your kind support now it works just fine, i use multiple header and .cpp files, so i somehow end up using it at the end of all inclusions.