# Why do I get this "Unknown sensor type" when creating Vulkan surface?

Tags: c++, sdl, game-engine, game-development, vulkan

I am trying to set up a basic Vulkan application using SDL and ran over a problem when trying to create a Vulkan Surface. I set up a small logging info that states: Unknown sensor type.

Here is where I create the surface:

```
VkSurfaceKHR surface;

SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo;
SDL_VERSION(&wmInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, &wmInfo);

VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR createInfo{};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
createInfo.hwnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;
createInfo.hinstance = wmInfo.info.win.hinstance;

if (vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(instance, &createInfo, nullptr, &surface) != VK_SUCCESS) {
  std::cerr << "Error creating surface: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And this is how I create the SDL window:

```
window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600,
                          SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

The error arises in the if statement. Does somebody know what might cause it?

Edit: I also tried using SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface (see comments) but I get an "Access violation" exception for "vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance)". If I remove the code related to the extensions being added to the createInfo then I get this error from the surface (VK_KHR_win32_surface extension is not enabled in the Vulkan instance) which seems fine since that code which should solve this is removed but the instance is created just fine. This is the code that also contain the extension:

```
appInfo = {};
appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
appInfo.pApplicationName = "Test";
appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
appInfo.pEngineName = "Test Engine";
appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

createInfo = {};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;

std::vector<const char*> extensions = {
    VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,
};

createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(extensions.size());
createInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = extensions.data();

VkInstance instance = NULL;
if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
  std::cerr << "Error creating instance: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: It would be a better idea to  use `SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface` instead.

Comment: @user7860670 Actually I tried this, but when I added the surface extension (VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME) to the VkInstanceCreateInfo it raised an error when creating the instance. Something like: Access violation reading location 0x000001FE0000001D

Comment: “[Cannot use vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR to create vulkan surface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42959758/7796092)” may be what you’re looking for. Aside: you’re calling `SDL_GetError` in the error handling section for a Vulkan function call. I would not expect that to return anything sensical.

Comment: @SafelyFast Unfortunately the error occurs while having that header added. I knew that it should be there in order for things like VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR to be seen in the application, so it's not like vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR is undefined (in the first implementation). Indeed, SDL_GetError is pretty much useless :((